# Tensorflow : Extract value from string tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensor -
tf.Tensor(b'ISIC_2637011', shape=(), dtype=string)

How do I extract value from here?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the value of tf.string tensor you can use :

```
s = tf.constant("You're")

st_value = ''.join ([chr(char) for char in tf.strings.unicode_decode(s,
                      input_encoding='UTF-8').numpy()])
```